# pyspark cache() dataframe issue

Tags: caching, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have program written in order to parallelize the process, cache has been applied after certain transformations on dataframe's. Lets say:

```
df1 = df.filter()
df3 = df1.join(df2, join_cond, "left")
df3.cache()    #ex: it has col1, col2, col3, col4 columns

After cache, we have some other steps to take care:
#1
df4 = df3.select(df3.col1, df3.col2)
df4.filter(df3.col1 > 500).show()
#2
df5 = df3.select(df3.col3, df3.col4)
df5.filter(df3.col4 > 2000)

df3.unpersist()
```

So, in this process if any issue or error occurs we have to uncache the dataframe or the old cache will destroy automatically when we are rerunning the program.

Could you please help me how the **cache()** will work if there is any kind of failures in the program at a certain point of time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

cache persists the lazy evaluation result in memory, so after the cache, any transformation could directly from scanning the df in memory and start working.

action vs transformation, action leads to a non-rdd non-df object like in your code `.show()`, transformation leads to another rdd/spark df, like in your code `.filter`, `.select`, `.join`

just based on your code snippet, there is no problem, your df4's dependency is just scanned df3 -> df4 and there is just one action. But if you want to call `df5.filter().show()` or `df4.show()` again, it will become a problem. Because you unpersist df3, there is no data in memory, in order to regenerate df4, the spark application need to start from df1 -> df2 -> df3 -> df4.

Does unpersist break your code? no, but definitely influence your performance of your application. I will double-check whether a persisted df is no longer needed in any further downstream job, then unpersist it